# AutoMapper: Map a source property on destination base

Tags: automapper

Here are two classes that I need to map, on the left side:

```
class HumanSrc {
    public int IQ;
    public AnimalSrc Animal;
}
class AnimalSrc {
    public int Weight;
}
```

on the right side are the same objects, but composed using inheritance:

```
class HumanDst : AnimalDst {
   public int IQ;
}
class AnimalDst {
    public int Weight;
}
```

so the mapping I need is:

```
humanSrc.IQ -> humanDst.IQ 
humanSrc.Animal.Weight -> humanDst.Weight;
```

I can easily do this mapping explicitly, but I have several classes that all derive from Animal, and Animal class is large, so I would prefer to map Animal once, and then have that included in every derived class mapping.

I looked at .Include<> method, but I do not think it supports this scenario.

Here is the essence of what I am looking for (pseudo-code):

```
// define animal mapping
var animalMap = Mapper.CreateMap<AnimalSrc, AnimalDst>().ForMember(dst=>dst.Weight, opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.Weight);
// define human mapping
var humanMap = Mapper.CreateMap<HumanSrc, HumanDst>();
humanMap.ForMember(dst=>dst.IQ, opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.IQ));

// this is what I want. Basically I want to say:
// "in addition to that, map this child property on the dst object as well"
humanMap.ForMember(dst=>dst, opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.Entity));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround you can add BeforeMap with mapping base class. Probably it is not the best solution but at least it requires less mapping configuration:

```
humanMap.BeforeMap((src, dst) =>
{
   Mapper.Map(src.Animal, (AnimalDst)dst);
});
```